# Using the nlm function for optimization with multiple variables

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Can the nlm function be used for optimization with multiple variables? How would that work?

For instance: I want to find x and y so that f(x,y) is minimized. How would the nlm function work?

something like that?:

```
nlm(f,c(0.1,0.1))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a function that receives a vector:

```
f <- function(X) {
  x <- X[1]
  y <- X[2]
  (x-3.14)^2 + (y-6.28)^2
}
nlm(f,c(0.1,0.1))
```

Comment: Works perfectly for several functions, thanks! I try to understand what's going on: So you're basically designing a 2dim vector X ={x,y}, right?

Comment: Correct: the solver uses a single vector X instead of several scalar variables.

Comment: To be precise X is actually not 2 dimensional, but rather a 1 dimensional array with length 2.