# nlm with multiple variables in R

Tags: r, optimization, minimization, nlm

I am trying to use `nlm()` to minimize the SSE in a function. I'm having trouble with they syntax and getting `nlm()` to provide estimates for both variables. Eventually `t_1`, `t_2`, and `t_3` will be values pulled from a `data.frame` but I just assigned them numbers until I could get the `nlm()` to work. I have attempted solutions from these threads [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620277/r-how-can-the-nlm-function-be-used-for-optimization-with-multiple-variables) and [there](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-use-nlm-function-in-r.893523/), with no luck:

```
t_1 <- 1.91
t_2 <- 3.23
t_3 <- 4.20

fun <- function(s,y){
  (10 - s*(t_1-y + y*exp(-t_1/y)))^2+
    (20 - s*(t_2-y + y*exp(-t_2/y)))^2+
    (30 - s*(t_3-y + y*exp(-t_3/y)))^2
}

## Testing the function
fun(9.57,1.13)
[1] 0.9342627
```

I have tried multiple approaches for my nlm syntax. With 2 varaibles I believe I have to insert an array for p but when I've tried that it hasn't worked. None of these solutions below have worked:

```
# Attempt 1
p = array(c( 1,0), dim=c(2,1) ) 
ans <- nlm(fun, p)

# Attempt 2
ans <- nlm(fun, c( 0.1, 0.1))

# The first two return a "Error in f(x, ...) : argument "y" is missing, with no default"
# Attempt 3 returns a "invalid function value in 'nlm' optimizer" error

ans <- nlm(fun, c( 0.1, 0.1), y = c(1,1))
```

I'm sure there are several errors in my code but I'm not sure where. This task is more complex than I've attempted before as I'm relatively new to R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely to the `nlm` function. It asks only one argument. One solution is :

```
fun <- function(x){
  s <- x[1]
  y <- x[2]
  (10 - s*(t_1-y + y*exp(-t_1/y)))^2+
    (20 - s*(t_2-y + y*exp(-t_2/y)))^2+
    (30 - s*(t_3-y + y*exp(-t_3/y)))^2
}

p <- array(c(0.4, 0.4), dim = c(2, 1))
# p <- c(0.4, 0.4)
ans <- nlm(f = fun, p = p)
```

Both `vector` or `array` work however you can't give two arguments like you did.

**EDIT**

In numerical optimization the initial point is really important. I advise you to use `optim` function which is less sensitive of misspecification of initial point.

One idea is to do like this, you make a grid of many initial points and you select the one which give you the best result :

```
initialisation <- expand.grid(seq(1, 3, 0.5),
                              seq(1, 3, 0.5))
res <- data.frame(optim = rep(0, nrow(initialisation)),
                  nlm = rep(0, nrow(initialisation)))

for(i in 1:nrow(initialisation)){
  res[i, 1] <- optim(as.numeric(initialisation[i, ]), fun)$value
  res[i, 2] <- try(nlm(f = fun, p = as.numeric(initialisation[i, ]))$minimum, silent = T)
}
res
```

I insist that with the example above the `optim` function is realy more stable. I advise you to use it if you have no other constrains.

You can check function parameters thanks to `?nlm`.

I hope it helps.

**EDIT 2**

```
fun <- function(x){
  s <- x[1]
  y <- x[2]
  (10 - s*(t_1-y + y*exp (-t_1/y)))^2+
    (20 - s*(t_2-y + y*exp(-t_2/y)))^2+
    (30 - s*(t_3-y + y*exp(-t_3/y)))^2
}
```

I choose this initial point because it seems nearer to the optimal one.

```
p <- c(10, 1)

ans <- nlm(f = fun, p = p)
```

You can obtain your two parameters like this :
s is :

```
s <- ans$estimate[1]
```

y is :

```
y <- ans$estimate[2]
```

You also have the optimal value which is :

```
ans$minimum :
0.9337047
fun(c(s, y)) :
0.9337047
```

My second post, the edit is just their to alight the fact that optimisation with `nlm` function is a bit tricky because you need ta carefully choose initial value.

The `optim` also an optimisation function for R is more stable as in the example I give with many initialization points.

`expand.grid` function is useful to obtain a grid like this :

```
initialisation <- expand.grid(s = seq(2, 3, 0.5),
                                y = seq(2, 3, 0.5))

initialisation :

   s   y
1 2.0 2.0
2 2.5 2.0
3 3.0 2.0
4 2.0 2.5
5 2.5 2.5
6 3.0 2.5
7 2.0 3.0
8 2.5 3.0
9 3.0 3.0
```

res `data.frame` gives you the minimum obtain with different initials values.
You see that the first initials values give you no good result for `nlm` but relatively stable one for `optim`.

```
res <- data.frame(optim = rep(0, nrow(initialisation)),
                  nlm = rep(0, nrow(initialisation)))

for(i in 1:nrow(initialisation)){
  res[i, 1] <- optim(as.numeric(initialisation[i, ]), fun)$value
  res[i, 2] <- if(is.numeric(try(nlm(f = fun, p = as.numeric(initialisation[i, ]))$minimum, silent = T)) == T){
    round(nlm(f = fun, p = as.numeric(initialisation[i, ]))$minimum, 8)
  }else{
    NA
  }
}
```

`try` function is just their to avoid the loop to break. The `if` is to put NA at the right place.

```
res :
optim         nlm
1 0.9337094        <NA>
2 0.9337058  0.93370468
3 0.9337054        <NA>
4 0.9337101  0.93370468
5 0.9337125 61.18166446
6 0.9337057  0.93370468
7 0.9337120  0.93370468
8 0.9337080  0.93370468
9 0.9337114  0.93370468
```

When there is `NA` values it meens that `nlm` doesn't  work well because of initialization. I advise you to choose `optim` if you don't need really precise optimisation because of its stability.

To an extensive discussion on `optim` vs `nlm`, you may have a look [their](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9535/when-should-i-not-use-rs-nlm-function-for-mle). In your specific case `optim` seems to be a better choice. I don't know if we could generalise a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the first solution and it gave me error messages. In the second solution, it provided a single value for the estimate (6.6) instead of 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just re-ran it with your edits and it seems to work. What is your strategy with choosing the initial array values? Will poor choices affect the outcome of the estimates?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure! I run your code and get output for 'nlm' and 'optim'. But I'm not sure where these values fit in to my original question for the optimal values of s and y. The first solution in your current answer gives me two estimates  when I run the `nlm`. I'm sorry for the further questions but this is more complicated than my current r skills! Just trying to understand what you're providing.

Comment: Yes that helped a lot, thank you! I think there are still some tweaks I have to make to the function though. I am re-creating an Excel Solver sheet that performs this task. For those t_1, t_2, and t_3 values, the solver gives the minimum SSE at estimates of `s=9.57; y = 1.13'.  I'll keep playing with the working code you gave me. Thank you again!